# NoReverseMatch at /sessions/exercise/6/update/

Tags: django, url, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm going crazy here.

According to the Django debugger there's no reverse match for the pattern I'm requesting, but it's identical to my URL path in urls.py, and I am passing the object id as the required argument.

> NoReverseMatch at /sessions/exercise/4/update/
>
> Reverse for 'exercise_update' with no arguments not found. 1
> pattern(s) tried: ['sessions/exercise/(?P[0-9]+)/update/$']
>
> Error during template rendering

This is my html

```
<button><a href="{% url 'sessions:exercise_update' exercise.id %}">Update exercise</a></button>
```

This is my URL path

```
path('exercise/<int:pk>/update/', MyExerciseUpdate.as_view(), name='exercise_update'),
```

The view is just a generic update view.

```
class MyExerciseUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Exercise
    fields = ['my_fields']
```

I've tried displaying the `exercise.id` just to see if it exists, and it does. How come there is no argument?

Also, I use this path for a detail view in another page and it works just fine

```
<a href="{% url 'sessions:exercise_detail' exercise.id %}">{{ exercise.name }}</a>
```

Help, please.

This is my entire urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path, include
from sessions.views import RoutineList, RoutineDetail, ExerciseDetail, SessionCreate, SessionDetail, ExerciseUpdate
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


app_name = 'sessions'

urlpatterns = [
    path('all_routines/', RoutineList.as_view(), name='routine_list'),
    path('routine/<int:pk>/', RoutineDetail.as_view(), name='routine_detail'),
    path('exercise/<int:pk>/detail', ExerciseDetail.as_view(), name='exercise_detail'),
    path('exercise/<int:pk>/update/', ExerciseUpdate.as_view(), name='exercise_update'),
    path('new/', SessionCreate.as_view(), name='session_create'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', SessionDetail.as_view(), name='session_detail'),
    
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Show your `urls.py`

Comment: Your issue is in your html file : `{% url 'sessions:exercise_update' exercise.id %}`, here `exercice.id` is `None`  for one reason or another.

Comment: @Rvector I added my urls.py. Also, you say that exercise.id must be None, but I tried`<p>{{ exercise.id }}</p>`  in my html and the id is right there on the page. Is there any other way I can test the id value?

Comment: What is the view that throw this error ? Normaly it happens when you want open a link ... On which link or button do you click and this error happens ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the html of the *form*. The form's url was lacking the exercise.id argument so it threw the no argument error:

```
<form action="{% url 'sessions:exercise_update' %}" method="post">
```

Solution:

```
<form action="{% url 'sessions:exercise_update' exercise.id %}" method="post">
```

It seems very silly now, but it took me forever to figure out where the problem was.